# Is there a way I can run a Database.SqlQuery as async?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
var sql = @"Select 
                case when Test.TestTypeId = 1 then Exam.Name
                     when Test.TestTypeId = 2 then Topic.Name
                end as Name,
                Test.Title,
                Test.TestId,
                Test.QuestionsCount
            FROM Test
            LEFT JOIN Exam ON Test.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
            LEFT JOIN Topic ON Test.TopicId = Topic.TopicId
            WHERE Test.TestStatusId = 1 -- Current";
var tests = db.Database.SqlQuery<TestDTO>(sql).ToList();
```

I was looking for an async method for this but it does not seem to exist. Is there a way that I can run this async?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework 6 you just need to specify

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

at the top of your file.

`ToListAsync` is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` declared in `System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions`

Comment: As you said, `ToListAsync` is only to `IQueryable`, `SqlQuery` returns `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @JeanCarlos No, it returns `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`, which implements `IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>` as well as methods such as `ToListAsync<T>` directly.