# Call stored procedure from EF asynchronously using C# inside async method

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, async-await, entity-framework-6

We are moving to Entity Framework, however we have a large number of stored procedures. If our Web API uses an async/await pattern all the way to the stored procedure call, how do I handle the call? Can I/should I make it async as well?

I have a db context and I can call my stored procedure `Foo` synchronously. This works however the calling code is all wrapped with async/await keywords. The stored procedure in question is also a `Select` and not an `Insert/Update/Delete`. I cannot use `ToListAsync()` on the `context.Foo` call, if I try

```
context.Database.ExecutSQLCommandAsync()
```

I only get a `Task<int>` back and not my object. Is there a best practice here?

```
public async Task<List<FooData>> GetFoo(string param)
{
    List<FooData> dataList = new List<FooData>();

    using(dbEntities context = new dbEntities(connectionstring))
    {
        //  this runs as expected
        var result =  context.Foo(param).ToList();

        if(result != null)
        {
            result.ForEach(delegate(Foo_Result item)
                               {
                                   //  load object
                               });
        }
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

I suppose I could do this

```
var result = await Task.Run(()=> context.Foo(param).ToList());
```

but this is an Entity Framework db call and not an CPU intensive process. Is there a best practice to follow here? Thanks

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24454001/2030565

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with a directly invoked stored proc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a result set, then you'll need `Database.SqlQuery`.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public async Task<IList<Foo>> GetFooAsync(int n)
    {
       var query = base.Database.SqlQuery<Foo>("exec fooStoredProc @n",
           new SqlParameter("@n", n));
       return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

With usage

```
public async Task Exec()
{
    MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
    var foos = await db.GetFooAsync(1);
}
```

This assumes your stored proc returns fields that match up to your Foo class.