# How to show animation while the code is being processed in an event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I'm doing this in C# WPF and Blend

My Thread for animation does not work correctly it mean's when I click on the button.

in a few moment animation will run but after In a short moment suddenly animation will stop until the code of query for get data from database in Click Event To end.

how to fix this? I want to show animation until code is processing in an event.

XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
     <Storyboard x:Key="RotationBtn">
         <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Command4">
             <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="720"/>
         </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
 </Window.Resources>
  <Window.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseDown" SourceName="Command4">
             <BeginStoryboard x:Name="RotationBtn_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RotationBtn}"/>
         </EventTrigger>
     </Window.Triggers>
    
     <Grid>
    
 <Button x:Name="Command4" Content="Next Stage" Margin="599,406,304,84"   Width="130" Height="37" FontSize="8" Click="Command4_Click" Background="#FFDDDDDD" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
             <Button.RenderTransform>
                 <TransformGroup>
                     <ScaleTransform/>
                     <SkewTransform/>
                     <RotateTransform/>
                     <TranslateTransform/>
                 </TransformGroup>
             </Button.RenderTransform>
         </Button>
    
  </Grid>
```

C# code:

```
  private void Command4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
             new Thread(() =>
      {
          App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
          {
               Storyboard sb = TryFindResource("RotationBtn") as Storyboard;
               Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, Command4);
               sb.Begin();
           });
      }).Start();
         var MyQuery = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<DB_Cust>("SELECT * FROM Customers").ToList();
 }
```

Result of The result of the upper lines ↑:

[image]

**what I need** is something like this simulated:

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand in what thread you are at every line. Starting in `Command4_Click`, you're in the UI thread. then you create a new thread, which will then do `Dispatcher.Invoke`. After `Thread.Start()`, if the background thread had enough time to start invoke on the main thread, the SQL query will wait until the background thread is done invoking on the main thread. If the query has time to start before `Dispatcher.Invoke`, the background thread will have to wait before the query is done, since the query is done on the main thread. What I think you need, is to start a background thread for the query. For example:

```
private void Command4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = TryFindResource("RotationBtn") as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, Command4);
    sb.Begin();

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        var MyQuery = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<DB_Cust>("SELECT * FROM Customers").ToList();
    }).Start();
}
```

There might be a case where you need to execute something on the main thread after the query, in which case it's probably simpler to go with an async method. Example:

```
// async void isn't usually a good idea, but for event handlers it's considered ok.
private async void Command4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = TryFindResource("RotationBtn") as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, Command4);
    sb.Begin();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var MyQuery = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<DB_Cust>("SELECT * FROM Customers").ToList();
    });
    
    // Do UI Stuff
    MessageBox.Show("Some text to display", "Window caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
}
```

Comment: Maybe also use [ToListAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24454001/1136211) instead of Task.Run.

Comment: after that query maybe I want to show a dialog box how can I do that when I using this you wrote them ? My mean i want to show animation at start of click event to when is done something like loader

Comment: if i do this animation will show correctly but click event not working correctly            decimal i = 0;
                while (i < 20)
                {
                  i++;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Test");

Comment: and you second solution have this error :     .     System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Angle'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.'

Comment: The `InvalidOperationException` comes from your animation code, something isn't quite right in this. Since it's not in a `Dispatcher.Invoke`, it surfaces in your UI thread. That's why you're seeing it. Not sure I understand what you're trying to do... Do you want to show a dialog box when the animation ends?

Comment: Yes Please thanks for taking you time answer to me

Comment: How to show dialog box like yes and no in end of it ?

Comment: I just edited the answer, adding the message box. Not really related to the question but it's a quick one. If this answers your question correctly, please mark it as the answer. Thank you!